# C# compare pixelformats

Tags: c#, image, pixelformat

How can i compare pixel formats of 2 images?

i have tried this:

```
if (img1.PixelFormat > img2.PixelFormat)
```

but "Format8bppIndexed" got rated as being bigger than "Format24bppRgb"

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: First it would be goot to know what "bigger" means; what would the order of those for instance be: `Format16bppArgb1555`, `Format16bppGrayScale`, `Format16bppRgb555` and `Format16bppRgb565`

Comment: i'll settle with the one with the highest color depth. i was looking at those enum values. im not sure wich one to put at top and put them in order that has the lowest color depth. msdn isnt really clear about this.

Comment: Well, there is no "greater color depth" really - they are different, but I couldn't say which one is bigger than another either. You need to find out what your needs are before you implement it...

Comment: well i mean what ever pic has a better quality, is good enough. in this case i'll just settle for highest color depth.

Comment: Arguably one could say that the `Format16bppRgb555` is the least quality. But `Format16bppArgb1555` is identical but it does have a one-bit alphy channel, does that quaify as better? If yes, how does that compare to `Format16bppRgb565` which has twice as many green shades as the other two, but no alpha channel? Or `Format16bppGrayScale`, which has a whopping 65504 distinct gray shades that the others don't have, but no color?

Comment: i get your point, i never got this deep working with pictures and its quality. so its kind of hard to tell which is better if i understand what you just said.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is valid, but you are just comparing the **value** of the enumeration so the result will depend on the order the values were defined in.

If you need to compare the formats of the images you will have to build up the rules yourself. Which value is "greater than" another will depend on your application.

As [@Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) suggests in his comment you could create a `Dictionary` keyed with the `PixelFormat` that returns the correct relative values (colour depth) for your comparisons to return sensible results and use that for your tests.

Comment: i see... how can i change this so that i can compare the color depth of the images?

Comment: @Yustme - You could create a lookup dictionary keyed by the different `PixelFormat` enum values where the values are in color depth order and use this for your tests.

Comment: Two ways I can think of (assuming there is not a specialized method I haven't found just yet). You could just create a dictionary with the name of the method and assign a value you prefer, or you could use something like the GetPixel() method to grab a pixel, and compare the byte makeups. The second way might work in more situations, but it may not be as precise as the former.

Comment: could you please show me a small code sample? i dont really understand it. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the images by their bit depths, try the following, this worked for me:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the bit depth of <paramref name="image"/>.
/// </summary>
public static int GetBitDepth(this Image image)
{
    return ((int) image.PixelFormat >> 8) & 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: Peculiar how they hid that information in an enum... but the `Image.GetPixelFormatSize()` function already exists to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since it seems no one has actually posted the obvious answer on it... `Image.GetPixelFormatSize(pixelformat)` returns the amount of used bits per pixel for the given pixel format. So for `Format16bppArgb1555` it would return `16`.

```
Int32 pixSize1 = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(img1.PixelFormat);
Int32 pixSize2 = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(img2.PixelFormat);
if (pixSize1 > pixSize2)
{
    ...
}
```

Though I really wonder why you would ever check that, unless it is to differentiate between indexed formats, where conversion to lower BPP could mean that the higher palette indices you have become impossible to write.